# VBS cannot create folder

Tags: vbscript

For some reason the following code does not work for me... I'm trying to learn VBS and I've been piecing together some code from resources on Google. I cannot figure out why I can't get this to work.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, objComputer
Dim objFSO, objFSOText, objFolder, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile, MakeObject

strDirectory = "C:\test"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
Wscript.Echo strDirectory & " already exists"
Else
Wscript.Echo "The folder " & strDirectory & " does not exist"
Wscript.Echo "The folder " & strDirectory & " has just been created"
End if

Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: Define "does not work".  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hey, I pulled an idiot move and forgot to add the directory create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what Ekkehard.Horner is trying to say is this:

If you add the following to your script it will work. Rookie mistake, but good work, keep trying at it.. it will eventually make sense!

> Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)

Here is your script with the added code and a note where to add it...

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, objComputer
Dim objFSO, objFSOText, objFolder, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile, MakeObject

strDirectory = "C:\test"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
Wscript.Echo strDirectory & " already exists"
Else
Wscript.Echo "The folder " & strDirectory & " does not exist"
'Below is the added line
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
Wscript.Echo "The folder " & strDirectory & " has just been created"
End if

Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: Thank you for spelling it out for me, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the question whether you are (or should be) allowed to create folders in C:\ - without something like

```
objFSO.CreateFolder strDirectory
```

(perhaps between those two `WScript.Echo`s in your `Else` branch) nothing will happen.